# Alarm Clock using DELPHI XE5 and Android

Tags: android, delphi

did someone already find the correct way to program an alarm clock using DEPHI XE 5 and Android OS?

I found this code , but it does not work/compile at all:

```
procedure TNotificationsForm.btnSendScheduledNotificationClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Notification: TNotification;
  begin

  { verify if the service is actually supported }
  if NotificationC.Supported then     //  compile error here 
  begin.Supported
    Notification := NotificationC.CreateNotification;    //  compile error here
    try
      Notification.Name := 'MyNotification';
     Notification.AlertBody := 'Delphi for Mobile is here!';

     { Fired in 10 second }
      Notification.FireDate := Now + EncodeTime(0,0,10,0);

   { Send notification in Notification Center }
   NotificationC.ScheduleNotification(Notification);
   finally
      Notification.DisposeOf;
    end;
   end
 end;
```

The first error is that NotificationC.Supported this property does not exist

Comment: Your "compile error" does not have a number or associated text?

Comment: forgot to drop the component , my fault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should mention that the code is based on one of the sample applications distributed with XE5. They can be found in the Start Menu entry for XE5 under **Samples**, or in the default **C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\MobileCodeSnippets\Notifications** folder (Windows 7).

It appears you've forgotten to drop the `TNotificationCenter` component (available on the Component Palette's **Services** page) on the form and name it `NotificationC` as the demos do. Once you've done that, your code compiles just fine.

When you mention that you get a "compile error" in a question here, it's important to **include the error message**. We can't see your screen from where we are. :-) You have that exact information right in front of you, so there's no excuse for not including it. The **Messages** window will even copy the exact message to the clipboard for you to paste here, if you right-click the error line.